# react-native-mock testing ReferenceError: Map is not defined

Tags: npm, react-native, mocha.js

I have writing some simple tests for React Native and running them on [CircleCI](https://circleci.com), but I get the follow error: ReferenceError: Map is not defined

I am aware that Map is a new ES6 feature but unsure of why I am getting this error. My test script includes `--compilers babel-core/register` but it does not look like babel is compiling some code in the [react-native-mock](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-mock/blob/master/src/api/AppState.js#L8) library.

I do not think this is specific to react-native-mock, but I did notice that library requires `babel-core/register` in their [test script](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-mock/blob/master/package.json#L8): `"test": "mocha --require babel-core/register test/**/*.js",`

I tried that as well and got a `Error: Cannot find module 'js:babel-core/register'` despite my having babel-core in my saved dependencies.

Any constructive help would greatly be appreciated.

```
$ npm test

> BlocMessenger@0.0.1 test /home/ubuntu/Messenger
> mocha --require react-native-mock/mock.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive App/**/__tests__/*.test.js


/home/ubuntu/Messenger/node_modules/react-native-mock/build/api/AppState.js:18
  change: new Map(),
              ^
ReferenceError: Map is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Messenger/node_modules/react-native-mock/build/api/AppState.js:18:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/ubuntu/Messenger/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:134:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Messenger/node_modules/react-native-mock/build/react-native.js:66:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/ubuntu/Messenger/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:134:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Messenger/node_modules/react-native-mock/mock.js:1:85)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/ubuntu/Messenger/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:134:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at args (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:310:3)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:309:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

npm test returned exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this required me to add a circle.yml and specify the node v5.0.0. This enabled circle.yml understand what `new Map`  was doing. For whatever reason it would not work without this check

```
// circle.yml

machine:
  node:
    version: 5.0.0
```

https://github.com/Bloc/Messenger/blob/master/circle.yml#L3